# Sublime Text - jump to first search result with keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, sublimetext

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> will select every instance.
I want to go to the selected occurrence. In IntelliJ I can do it with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I have 2 simple questions:

1. How to switch between occurrences?
2. Shortcut for set cursor on first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with combinations of built-in shortcuts.

1. Move the cursor to the beginning of the file. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479195/sublime-text-2-how-to-position-cursor-at-begin-end-of-buffer/15403743#15403743) for how to do this on every platform.
2. Open the find panel and start typing your search query. As you type, the first match will be highlighted.
3. <kbd>Esc</kbd>

You should now have the first match selected.

If you want to switch between occurrences, then do steps 1 and 2 above. In the find panel, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> will cycle forward and backward between matches.